# DAX measure to add error opportunity based on department name

Tags: dax, powerpivot, measure

I have a table with the following columns: `Sale number, Department, Site, Audit outcome`

I'm trying to create a Measure `Error Opportunity` - if Department name is equal to A or B, then error opportunity = 2 else it should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Try something like that:

```
Error Opportunity =
    var Dep = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Department])
return
    IF(
        OR(Dep = "A", Dep = "B"),
        2,
        1
    )
```

I assumed that the name of your table is Table1. Let me know if it works for you.

[image]